# how to compare between the value from a able and entered value

Tags: php, mysql

here is short description of what i want to do:
i want the member enter the sensor id, but if this sensor id is not saved in the database by the admin in table name "availblesensors" it will not add this user to the database.

i worte this if satatment

```
$sid=strip_tags($_POST['sid']);
$sidcheck=mysql_query("SELECT sid FROM availblesensors WHERE sid='$sid'");

        $count3=mysql_num_rows($sidcheck);
        if($count3 = 0){
        die("This sensor is not availble!");
    }
```

i think if satament is not worked, because each time i entered sid (either if it is availble in availblesensors or not) it is add the user, but it is saved 0 not the value that i was entered.

and here is my whole code if needed!

```
<?php

session_start();?>
<?php
require("noCache.php");
?>
<html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Admin Page</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon-yui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon-replace.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Myriad_Pro_400.font.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Myriad_Pro_700.font.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Myriad_Pro_600.font.js"></script>
</head>


<body>
<div class="main">

    <header>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <h1><a href="index.php" id="logo"> Biz</a></h1>

        </div>
        <nav>
            <ul id="menu">
                <li class="alpha"><a href="index.php"><span><span>Home</span></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="About.html"><span><span>About</span></span> </a></li>
                <li><a href="Projects.html"><span><span>Projects</span></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="Contacts.php"><span><span>Contacts</span></span></a></li>
                <li class="omega"><a href="Services.html"><span><span>Services</span></span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        </br></br>

</header>


<head>
<!-- CSS Stylesheet -->
<style type="text/css">
html{

}
body{
    text-align:center;

}

</style>
</head>
<?php
if($_SESSION['username']){
include ("connection.php");
$id=$_SESSION['uid'];

}?>

<?php 

    $submit= $_POST['submit'];
    $name= strip_tags($_POST['name']);  
    $dusername= strtolower(strip_tags($_POST['dusername']));
    $password= strip_tags($_POST['password']);
    $repassword= strip_tags($_POST['repassword']);
    $date=date("y-m-d");
    $sid=strip_tags($_POST['sid']);
    $phone=strip_tags($_POST['phone']);

if($submit){
//open data base
$connet=mysql_connect("localhost","root","hahaha1");
mysql_select_db("senior");

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
// my problem is i want to check the entered sensor by id if was availble or not, by checking if the admin added it into the database or not
    $sidcheck=mysql_query("SELECT sid FROM availblesensors WHERE sid='$sid'");

    $count3=mysql_num_rows($sidcheck);
    if($count3 = 0){
    die("This sensor is not availble!");
    }

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    $namecheck=mysql_query("SELECT dusername FROM sensorusers WHERE dusername='$dusername'");
    $count=mysql_num_rows($namecheck);
    if($count!=0){
    die("username already exist!");
    }
    $emailcheck=mysql_query("SELECT sid FROM sensorusers WHERE sid='$sid'");
    $count2=mysql_num_rows($emailcheck);
    if($count2!=0){
    die("This sensor already used!");
    }



if($name && $dusername && $password && $repassword && $phone && $sid ){



if($password==$repassword){
if (strlen($name)>25 || strlen($dusername)>25){
echo"<h3><font color='red'>Length of username or name is Too Long!</font></h3>";
}

elseif  (strlen($password)>12 || strlen($repassword)<6){
echo"<h3><font color='red'>Password must be between 6 and 12 characters!</font></h3>";}


elseif(ctype_alpha($name)=== false)
{
echo"<h3><font color='red'>Name must not contains numbers!</font></h3>";
}

else{
$password=md5($password);
$repassword=md5($repassword);


$queryreg=mysql_query(" 
INSERT INTO sensorusers VALUES('','$name','$dusername','$password','$date','$sid','$phone','$id')
");
//  success 
die("You have been Create new sensor user successfully !! <a href='member.php'>click here to return to Your page</a>");
}


}



else{ echo"<h3><font color='red'>The two passwords not match!</font color='red'></h3>"; }

}
else echo"<h3><font color='red'>Please fill in <b>all</b> feilds!</font></h3>";


}   


?>
















<br>
<div align='left'>
<b>

<center> Create new driver: </center> </br></br></br>
<font color='blue'> Please fill all the information to create a new driver that you want to monitor: </font></br></br></br>
 <form name='f' action='createsensoruser.php' method='POST' >

<ul>


<li id="foli9"      class="    ">
    <label class="desc" id="title9" for="name">
        Name

            </label>
    <div>
        <input id="Field9"          name="name"     value=""        type="text"             class=""            value=""            maxlength="255"             tabindex="12"   size="25"                   /> 
    </br>
    </div>
    </li>
<li id="foli9"      class="    ">
    <label class="desc" id="title9" for="dusername">
        Username

            </label>
    <div>
        <input id="Field9"          name="dusername"    value=""        type="text"             class=""            value=""            maxlength="255"             tabindex="12"   size="25"                   /> 
    </div>
    </li>

<li id="foli55"         class="    ">
    <label class="desc" id="title55" for="pass">
        Password

            </label>
    <div>
        <input id="Field55"             name="password"             type="password"             class=""            value=""            maxlength="12"          tabindex="80"       size="25"               /> 
    </div>
    </li>

<li id="foli70"         class="    ">
    <label class="desc" id="title70" for="repass">
        Re-Enter your password

            </label>
    <div>
        <input id="Field70"             name="repassword"           type="password"             class=""            value=""            maxlength="12"          tabindex="81"       size="25"               /> 
    </div>
    </li>
<li id="foli9"      class="    ">
    <label class="desc" id="title9" for="sid">
        Sensor id

            </label>
    <div>
        <input id="Field9"          name="sid"  value=""        type="text"             class=""            value=""            maxlength="255"             tabindex="12"   size="25"                   /> 
    </div>
    </li>

<li id="foli9"      class="    ">
    <label class="desc" id="title9" for="phone">
        Phone number

            </label>
    <div>
        <input id="Field9"          name="phone"    value=""        type="text"             class=""            value=""            maxlength="255"             tabindex="12"   size="25"                   /> 
    </div>
    </li>


    </br>



                        <input  name="submit"  type="submit" value="submit"  />
                            <input type="reset" value="clear" />




</ul>
</form>
 </b>

 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($count3 = 0){
```

should be:

```
if($count3 == 0){
```

Otherwise you are assinging a value to $count3 of '0' opposed to comparing it's value to see if it's equal to '0'. That assignment will otherwise equal to true.

One method I use to prevent accidents like this is to put the constant first such as:

```
if(0 == $count3){
```

That way if I miss the other = sign PHP will error, rather than assign the value erroneously.

Comment: WAW,now the if statment worked, but in the databse it always save zero in the sid value, not the value that i entered, any help?

Comment: can you got to this line $queryreg=mysql_query(" 
INSERT INTO sensorusers VALUES('','$name','$dusername','$password','$date','$sid','$phone','$id')
"); and then echo out right after that line the following: echo $queryreg; and then post me the output. Need to see if it is a query problem or database problem.

Comment: it is print it for me 1 , by the way i used to add the sensor id again (which already added into the database but saved as 0) and it says that the sensor is already exist, which means it is know its value but it saved it as 0

Comment: Are you entering in an SID value in the form or should it be coming from session_id()?

Comment: i tried it this is the output:INSERT INTO sensorusers VALUES('','sarasayyar','saraaaa','e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e','12-12-11','sa','123','9') You have been Create new sensor user successfully !! click here to return to Your page
by the way sid=sd.. but in the database it is saved as a zero!

Comment: Please post the structure of your database table, as in field name, types etc. I believe you may have the wrong type set for that column.

Comment: this is availblesensors table
CREATE TABLE `availblesensors` (
  `sid` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `Desc` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
and this is sensorusers table:
CREATE TABLE `sensorusers` (
  `suid` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `dusername` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `sid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `phone` text NOT NULL,
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`suid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=21 ;

Comment: ok, how long is SID suppose to be in the form? You have maxlength as 255 for the form, but the field in database cannot support a size that long. What have you been inputting? It's likely going over the size limit so the value defaults to 0.

Comment: You have SID in database table as an INTEGER yet you are passing a STRING as the SID, so that wont work. Change the SID field in table to VARCAHR(255)

Comment: yyyyyyyyyyyessss, its worked!!!!! thhhhhank u very much i appreciate your helping

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
/* $sid = (int)$_POST['sid'];  uncomment this only if $sid is integer */

$sidcheck = mysql_query("SELECT sid FROM availblesensors WHERE sid='$sid'");
$result = mysql_query($sidcheck);
$isSIDinTheDataBase     =   mysql_num_rows($resultado);

if($isSIDinTheDataBase==0)
{
 /* ... */
}
```

In the future you can use prepared statements or pdo for our sql operations

Comment: i tried what you wrote the if statmet worked. but the value of sid which is saved in the database is always zero i don't know why

Comment: Try this: die( var_dump( $sid ) ); after $sid = $_POST['sid']; and post the result

Comment: you need to submit the form, and later post the result

Comment: No, complete and submit the form, and later post here the result.

Comment: Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in C:\AppServ\www\senior\try.php on line 88
username already exist!

Comment: thank youuu very much the problem is solved now, the problem was in the database, i decleared sid in one table as integer and in  the other table as varchar! thhhank u